# not enough space in <mat-select>. How to add multiple line <mat-option>?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I want to have under the option text additional lines which describe the option.
By default mat-select limits number of characters  and add "..." at the end of the line. I want to have multiple line option of needed.  stakckblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wj9svw
My code:

```
export class SelectOverviewExample {
  foods: Food[] = [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak longDescription longDescription longDescription longDescription longDescription'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza longDescription longDescription longDescription longDescription longDescription longDescription v v longDescription'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
  ];
}
```

html:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
      <b> some additional text text text text texttext </b>
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use following css :

```
    .mat-select-panel mat-option.mat-option {
      height: unset;
    }

   .mat-option-text.mat-option-text {
      white-space: normal;
    }
```

OR

```
/deep/ .mat-select-panel mat-option.mat-option {
  height: unset;
}

/deep/ .mat-option-text.mat-option-text {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

Sample demo is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-ndtstg

Comment: Unfortunately this only works with one mat-option item. Try to add a couple (like 19) to the stackblitz example, and you will see that selecting items by clicking does not work properly anymore, that is, the list scrolls on every click making it impossible to see what you selected.

Comment: Brain wanted to write 10+, hand typed 19.

Comment: @yglodt, I'm also having the same problem. How did you fix it?

Comment: @jeba I couldn't

Comment: @yglodt, Fixed by using this - https://github.com/angular/components/issues/18651#issuecomment-650787313

Comment: Works for me using `::ng-deep` instead of `/deep/`

Answer (score 9):

```
.mat-option {
  margin: 1rem 0;
  overflow: visible;
  line-height: initial;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
.mat-option i {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  opacity: 0.6;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;

}
```

This was also helpful

Comment: looking into `word-wrap`, `line-height` and `white-space` fixes this overflow issues most of the cases

Comment: `white-space: normal` is a better way .. please read about `pre-wrap` here https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/. It has the importance of line breaks

Answer (score 5):

I solved by writing a `MultiLineOptionDirective` that extends `<mat-option>` and calls the same `setLines()` function that `MatListItem` and `MatGridTile` do from `@angular/material/core`

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="mySelect">
    <mat-select-trigger>{{ mySelect.value }}</mat-select-trigger>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value" multiLineOption>
      <h4 mat-line>{{ food.value }}</h4>
      <p mat-line>{{ food.description }}</p>
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-multi-line-option

Edit: "extends" may be misinterpreted, extends as in a directive extends the functionality of an element not a class extends a base class.

Comment: I not sure why the directive is not applied to my html element. I just imported multiline moudule in my shared module and exported.

Comment: do you have multiLineOption on your mat-option

Comment: yes. I have the `multiLineOption` on my `mat-option`. It did not work before. Some css issue i think. Let me try again.

Answer (score 3):

This shows the long text in 2 columns.

In the .scss add: (You can remove the 3 last lines if you want that every row has the same height)

```css
.multiline-mat-option.mat-option {
    white-space: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    height: unset;
    padding-top: 0.9em;
    padding-bottom: 0.9em;
}
```

In the Html:

```html
<mat-option class="multiline-mat-option"...
```

Comment: This just duplicates the accepted answer from several years ago. How is this any different or better?

Comment: HI @andrew the accepted answer did not work in my project, besides that, this solution adds some padding to each element and does not use ng-deep.

Answer (score 2):

I recently came across this problem and after some debugging I found that you can reference the class associated with .

```
.mat-option {
  white-space: normal;
  line-height: normal;
}
```

This will wrap the text to the next line and adjust the height accordingly. You can also do `line-height: auto` if you're working with dynamic data.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following CSS.

```css
::ng-deep .mat-select-panel mat-option.mat-option {
    height: unset;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    padding-top: 0.9em;
    padding-bottom: 0.9em;
}

::ng-deep .mat-option-text.mat-option-text {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer an issue with Angular Material 16 (MDC), it now automatically adjusts the height of the `mat-option` based on its contents.