# How to show data In two line in mat-select?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

In mat-select the options have too long strings, selected option should be shown in two lines in same dropdown.

Now the string looks incomplete.

[incomplete string example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ua7gY.png)

```
<mat-form-field class="form-field">
    <mat-select formControlName="foo">
        <mat-option value="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
        </mat-option>
     </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I want somthing like this

[example complete selected option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XrAI.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [not enough space in <mat-select>. How to add multiple line <mat-option>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52832889/not-enough-space-in-mat-select-how-to-add-multiple-line-mat-option)

Answer (score 7):

There seem to be a few outdated answers.
As of Angular Material 11, you can do this easily by adapting the css of mat-option.

```html
<mat-option class="multiline-mat-option">
   <div>Line 1</div>
   <div>Line 2</div>
</mat-option>
```

```css
.multiline-mat-option.mat-option {
  white-space: normal;
  line-height: normal;
}
```